# Javascript for loop index variables become part of global scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

Perhaps I'm not aware of how `for` loop index variables get scoped, but I was very surprised when one of my loops didn't complete, seemingly because a function called from within a loop contained an `i` for its `for` loop index as well.

Here's a little script I put together to demonstrate this behavior:

```
var loopOne = function(test) {
    for(i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
        console.log(getMask(test));
};

var getMask = function(pass) {      
    var s = "";
    for (i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
        s = s + "*";
    }
    return s;      
};

loopOne('hello');
```

If I run this in Chrome and look at the console log, I should see `*****` five times. However, I only see it once. Upon further inspection, if I type `i` in the Chrome javascript console, it will output 6 ( `= 'hello'.length + 1`).  This makes me think that `i` has become a part of the global scope and is not limited to the scope of the `for` loop for which it was needed.

Is this correct?  If so, what's a better practice for defining the index variable of a `for` loop in javascript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Javascript, variables are scoped with the `var` keyword. When declaring variables with `var`, the variable is scoped to the current function. When assigning to a variable without using the `var` keyword, it is assumed you're talking about an already defined variable in the same or a higher scope. If none is found, the variable is created in the highest scope.

Bottom line: declare all your variables using `var`.

Comment: "If none is found, the variable is created in the highest scope."  That's just evil. Thanks for the explanation about scoping using `var`.  Now that you mention it, I should have remembered that.

Comment: @Ben Indeed, it's one of the many pitfalls of Javascript. AFAIK this is being/was rectified in the latest ECMAScript spec.

Comment: I think only if you add `"use strict"`.

Comment: Rember that javascript was intended as a simple, easy to use language. It also needs to support closures so assigning to undeclared idnetifiers is reasonabley common. So undeclared variables are added to the global object **when they are first assigned a value**, not before.

Comment: @Rob Added that as clarification.

Answer (score 10):

You should declare your loop index variable with `let`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) ...
```

That will declare and set the proper scope for the variable.

Answer (score 4):

When you declare your variables with `var`, you scope them to the current execution context.

When you don't, they become properties of the global object (`window` in a browser).